# Firebase con DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, firestore

Tengo un problema con DataTable al momento de obtener los datos , estoy trabajando con **onSnapshot** de firestore , el problema es que no me muestra los datos para listar en la tabla no se en que me equivoque me pueden ayudar porfavor

```
const $db = firebase.firestore();
$db.collection("Ciudad")
        .onSnapshot(doc => {
            doc.forEach(lista=>{
               $('#ListarCiudad').DataTable({
                    destroy: true,
                    processing: true,
                    data: lista,
                    columns: [
                        { data: "$codigo" },
                        { data: "$ciudad" },
                        { data: "$pais" },
                    ],
                    
                })
              
            })
        } ,error=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas añadir los valores y redibujar la tabla, te comparto un código que puede ayudarte.

```
$db.collection("Ciudad")
    .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        let ciudades = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            ciudades.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
        });
     ciudades.forEach(ciudad => {
         table.row.add([
             ciudad.codigo,
             ciudad.ciudad,
             ciudad.pais
         ]).draw(false);
     });
});
```

Donde `table` es la definición de tu DataTable, de esta manera puedes ver los cambios en la tabla en tiempo real y redibujar en caso de que haya un valor nuevo o se elimine uno desde la base de datos.